# unable to add UIButton on view

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, class, uibutton

I have class name called `HomeViewController`, inside `HomeViewController` i am adding `PageViewController`(i.e. APPChildViewController)

**Here is my code:**

`HomeViewController.h:`

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UIPageViewControllerDelegate>{
    NSUInteger Pageindex;
    APPChildViewController *childViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;
```

`HomeViewController.m:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    APPChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    self.pageController.delegate = self;
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self OnLoad]; //Method on APPChildViewController class
}
```

`APPChildViewController:`

```
-(void)OnLoad{

        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 130,130);
     // [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 30, 00, 15)];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

after writing this code in my `PageViewController`(i.e. APPChildViewController) i am unable to see button in my `APPChildViewController` class.

**Where i am doing mistake? please help and Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You have tried to add a title to the button or at least a backgroundcolor?

Comment: oh yes, really dude i forgot to check after adding backgroundcolor it works.

Comment: don't start method names with Capital letter, and don't use On prefix. iOS isn't DotNet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to add a title to the button or at least a backgroundcolor? :)

Answer (score 0):

as OnLoad is a method of `APPChildViewController`, you should use `[initialViewController OnLoad]`

Answer (score 0):

You've called the OnLoad method of HomeViewController not APPChildViewController - you would need to change the method call to [initialViewController OnLoad]